# Cronjob is still running even after deletion

Tags: python, cron

In one of my past project developed in Django python framework, I needed a cronjob to automate some process. I used this [django-cron](https://pypi.org/project/django-cron/) module and installed it as per their [documentation](https://django-cron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html). Everything was working as usual. Recently, the project was discontinued and every code and related processes were removed.

But I found that the cronjob related to that project is still running. I double checked with `crontab -e`, the cronjob is not there. I tried by reloading and restarting the cron daemon, even I restart the whole server, but in vain. If I check in `/var/log/syslog`, I still can see the cron is running every minute. Here is the output from syslog.

```
Jul 25 08:33:01 CRON[26412]: (ubuntu) CMD (cd /home/projects/pdf-generator && /home/venv/django/bin/python manage.py runcrons core.myapp.crons.PdfConversionCronJob)
```

The server is running Ubuntu 18.04.

Does anyone know what is going on and how to remove the cronjob for once and all?

Comment: Also look in the system-wide crontab file `/etc/crontab` and files in `/etc/cron.d`. If you're not logged in as user `ubuntu`, check their crontab explicitly with `sudo crontab -u ubuntu -l` for example

Comment: @steeldriver Perfect. It was hiding in `/etc/crontab`. I removed it and it's gone. If you add your comment as answer, I can accept it as answer.

Comment: Thanks - please see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as a user's personal crontab (editable/viewable via `crontab -e` or `crontab -l`), cron jobs for a user may be run from

- the system-wide crontab file, `/etc/crontab`
- a file in the `/etc/cron.d/` directory

If you are not currently logged in as user `ubuntu` you can check their personal crontab with `sudo crontab -u ubuntu -l` or `sudo -u ubuntu crontab -l`